# error: value show is not a member of String

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If in this case I want to `show` the `header` . Why I cannot write in the third line `header.show()`?
What I have to do to view the content of the header variable?

```
val hospitalDataText = sc.textFile("/Users/bhaskar/Desktop/services.csv")
val header = hospitalDataText.first() //Remove the header
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you use sparkContext (sc.textFile), you get an RDD**. You are getting the error because `header` is not a `dataframe` but a `rdd`. And `show` is applicable on `dataframe` or `dataset` only.

You will have to read the textfile with `sqlContext` and **not** `sparkContext`.

What you can do is use `sqlContext` and `show(1)` as

```
val hospitalDataText = sqlContext.read.csv("/Users/bhaskar/Desktop/services.csv")
hospitalDataText.show(1, false)
```

**Updated** for more clarification

`sparkContext` would create `rdd` which can be seen in

```
scala> val hospitalDataText = sc.textFile("file:/test/resources/t1.csv")
hospitalDataText: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = file:/test/resources/t1.csv MapPartitionsRDD[5] at textFile at <console>:25
```

And if you use `.first()` then the first string of the `RDD[String]` is extracted as

```
scala> val header = hospitalDataText.first()
header: String = test1,26,BigData,test1
```

Now answering your comment below, **yes** you can create `dataframe` from `header` string just created

Following will put the string in one `column`

```
scala> val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@3fc736c4

scala> import sqlContext.implicits._
import sqlContext.implicits._

scala> Seq(header).toDF.show(false)
+----------------------+
|value                 |
+----------------------+
|test1,26,BigData,test1|
+----------------------+
```

If you want each string in separate columns you can do

```
scala> val array = header.split(",")
array: Array[String] = Array(test1, 26, BigData, test1)

scala> Seq((array(0), array(1), array(2), array(3))).toDF().show(false)
+-----+---+-------+-----+
|_1   |_2 |_3     |_4   |
+-----+---+-------+-----+
|test1|26 |BigData|test1|
+-----+---+-------+-----+
```

You can even define the header names as

```
scala> Seq((array(0), array(1), array(2), array(3))).toDF("col1", "number", "text2", "col4").show(false)
+-----+------+-------+-----+
|col1 |number|text2  |col4 |
+-----+------+-------+-----+
|test1|26    |BigData|test1|
+-----+------+-------+-----+
```

More advanced approach would be to use `sqlContext.createDataFrame` with `Schema` defined

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `DataFrame` use `DataFrameReader` and `limit`:

```
spark.read.text(path).limit(1).show
```

otherwise just `println`

```
println(header)
```

Unless of course you want to use `cats` `Show`. With cats add package to `spark.jars.packages` and

```
import cats.syntax.show._
import cats.instances.string._

sc.textFile(path).first.show
```